# How to remove quotes from the model`s method return in the template?

Tags: angular, templates, typescript

I have a model like this.

```
export class Card {
    face: string;
    ....

    public getFaceCSS() {
        switch (this.face) {
        case 'H': return "&hearts;";
        case 'D': return '&diams;';
        case 'C': return '&clubs;';
        case 'S': return '&spades;';
        default: return '';
    }        
}
```

And when I try to print out it inside my template I get double quotes around my output.

```
<span class="suit">{{card.getFaceCSS()}}</span>
<span class="suit">"&spades;"</span>
```

How can I remove them?

Comment: Please check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45611221/5013099

Answer (score 0):

use {!! !!} instead of {{}}

```
<span class="suit">{!! card.getFaceCSS() !!}</span>
```

{{ $something }} echos $something after escaping i.e. it will convert html and css into string

{!! $something !!} echos $something **without** escaping

Answer (score 0):

Bind your faceCss to `[innerHtml]` attribute. See the example below:

> ```
> <span class="suit" [innerHTML]="card.getFaceCSS()"></span>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by binding.

```
<span class="suit" [innerHTML]="card.getFaceCSS()"></span>
```

Sorry.